# Why is my java method not working? (help a newbie)

Tags: java, methods, double

Please help me with one of my first java programs ever. I created a method "findCurrencyRate" that is supposed to return the rate of the selected currency (in this case USD) contained in the string "texto". I just keep getting the compilation error: "This method must return a result of type double". What is wrong with my code? Help me understand...

### Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String currency = "USD";
        System.out.println(findCurrencyRate(currency));
    }

    public static double findCurrencyRate(String Currency) {

        String text = "EUR 1.65 \n USD 8.56 \n YEN 0.34";
        Scanner file = new Scanner(text);
        file.useLocale(Locale.US);

        while (file.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = file.nextLine();
            Scanner linea = new Scanner(line);
            linea.useLocale(Locale.US);

            if (linea.next().equals(Currency)) {
                double currencyValue = linea.nextDouble();
                return currencyValue;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What will happen with your method if it gets to the end of the file without ever finding a match for `Currency`?

Answer (score 0):

If a method has the return type `double`, it is required to return a `double` in all cases, even if the loop or the `if` block is not executed.

A simple solution would be to add `return 0.0;` at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if `file.hasNextLine()` is `false`?  Or if `linea.next().equals(Currency)` is `false`?  The method doesn't return anything.  As the error message states, the method must return something.

So you need to ensure that something is returned:

```
public static double findCurrencyRate(String Currency) {

    // ... your existing code ...

    while (file.hasNextLine()) {

        // ... your existing code ...

    }

    // return some default value here

}
```

That way if the entire file is processed without ever finding the value to return, at least *something* is returned.

**Note:** If you truly don't want to return *anything* because exiting the loop without finding a match is some sort of error condition, then instead of returning a default value you can throw an exception.  Throwing an exception is a valid exit for a method, though with checked exceptions this would change the method signature of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String currency = "USD";
        System.out.println(findCurrencyRate(currency));
    }

    public static double findCurrencyRate(String Currency) {

        String text = "EUR 1.65 \n USD 8.56 \n YEN 0.34";
        Scanner file = new Scanner(text);
        file.useLocale(Locale.US);

        while (file.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = file.nextLine();
            Scanner linea = new Scanner(line);
            linea.useLocale(Locale.US);
            

            if(linea.next().equals(Currency)) {
                double currencyValue = linea.nextDouble();
                return currencyValue;
            }

        }
        return 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].